# Parsing Exception on reading remote config from Github in a Spring cloud project

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml, spring-cloud, snakeyaml

We have 2 micro services:

**config-service** and **my-actual-service**

We have a separate Git project that has all the springboot/springcloud configurations.

**my-actual-service** reaches out to **config-service** and **config-service** fetches the appropriate config from Github.

The config is loaded fine, but then it throws parsing error on the datasource section:

```
    org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.FailedToConstructEnvironmentException: 
Could not construct context for config=myconfig profile=dev label= includeOrigin=true; nested exception is while parsing a block mapping
     in 'reader', line 3, column 5:
            url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver ...
            ^
    expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
     in 'reader', line 5, column 23:
            password: {cipher}encrypted_password ...
                              ^
    
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NativeEnvironmentRepository.findOne(NativeEnvironmentRepository.java:165) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.findOne(AbstractScmEnvironmentRepository.java:64) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOneFromCandidate(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:195) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.findOne(MultipleJGitEnvironmentRepository.java:178) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
            at org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.lambda$findOne$3(ObservationEnvironmentRepositoryWrapper.java:75) ~[spring-cloud-config-server-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
```

This is the config:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:oracle:thin:@myserver:port:sid"
    username: USER
    password: {cipher}encrypted_password
```

Can't figure out what might be going on here. I tried the **url** with quotes, with double quotes and without any quotes with no change.

We are using Spring boot / cloud version: 3.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple thing, the whole password string, as it had curly braces, needed to be in single quotes, so like: `'{cipher}encrypted_password'`.

What threw me off was that it started complaining on the `url` line. The `url` line doesn't need to have single or double quotes.